# prefix vs postfix increment for sentinel values

Tags: operators, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

Using a very basic example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < value; i++)
```

Is there any difference whether I use i++ or ++i? I won't be reading i when it is being incremented, so being prefix or postfix wouldn't matter, but is there a difference in, for example, program efficiency or compiler optimization etc.?

Answer (score 0):

None.

It's possible in some languages for some types for there to be a difference in the performance of postfix and prefix, but not for built-ins like `int` and generally optimised away when the value isn't used. It's possible in some languages that you might find `doSomething(i); i++` or `doSomething(i); ++i` is marginally faster than `doSomething(i++);` because temporaries don't get optimised away.

Those cases are relatively rare, and not of a large impact.

Here though, it really won't make any difference in just about any of the languages that that code would be valid in.